# MongoDB authentication failed using spring mongodata

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I created a user and enable auth.everything works fine from terminal. I can authenticate to my readDB using credentials from terminal.It's working fine.

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.Testread",
    "user" : "testread",
    "db" : "admin",
    "credentials" : {
        "MONGODB-CR" : "************************"
    },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "read",
            "db" : "readDB"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can authenticate from terminal. When I tried to add user name nad pasword to my spring bean cinfiguartion it throws error

```
`not authorized for query on readDB.readEducation; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: not authorized for query on readDB.readEducation"`
```

I used same credentials as I used on terminal still not working.

My configuration file is

```
<mongo:db-factory id="readFactory" host="192.168.1.105"
        port="27017" dbname="readDB" username="testread" password="********" />
```

I am using

```
db version          v3.4.0
spring-data-mongodb 1.1.0.RELEASE
Spring framework    3.1.1.RELEASE
```

Comment: Are you really using MONGODB-CR instead of SCRAM-SHA-1 for authentication? Is their some reason why? Also the spring-data-mongodb `1.1.0` is quite old. Do you possibly mean `1.10.x` instead? Which would actually indicate a more recent release.

Comment: no any reason for using SCRAM-SHA-1 it just created by default while creating user.If I upgrade 1.1.0 to 1.10.X .I need to upgrade spring 4 that cause issues in autowired so I continue with 1.1.0

Comment: There's [still quite a few spring-mongodb-releases in between that](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent). `1.1.0` is released in 2012. You should take it to the limits of your other dependencies and then I would advise make sure the `SCRAM-SHA-1` authentication was in place instead. Any library releases supporting after MongoDB 3.x server should then simply support the new authentication method, and be well documented.

Comment: How to change MONGODB-CR to SCRAM-SHA-1?